# Ubuntu cannot connect to Android hotspot

Tags: 22.04, android, hot-spot

I tried connecting to a hotspot from Android 14 and Ubuntu just kept saying no internet but connected to the hotspot.

I tried via USB ethernet and also Bluetooth, the hotspot worked well on other devices e.g Windows, Smart Tv and other phones.

Ubuntu could only connect to Public hotspot/AP

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl NetworkManager service`. Also do: `service NetworkManager status` and `service --status-all`.